# How to modify JSON data in XML attribute in SQL server, if XML is having attribute which contains JSON like data having special characters

Tags: json, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-update

I have a very huge data to be updated but i'm stuck while modifying XML. i need to use modify(replace value of "" with ""). if i am using normal string it is modifying that data in XML, but in case of special characters it's saying "invalid entity reference using special characters".

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root><object attr="[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGH&quot;,&quot;Age&quot;:1}]"></object></root>'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/root/object/@attr)[1] with "[{&quote;Name&quote;:&quote;ABCD&quote;, &quote;Age&quote;:1}]"')
select @XML
```

I wanted to update this string as it is in that @attr with "" just for start and end of that string.

Ex:

```
<root>
   <object attr="[{&quote;Name&quote;:&quote;ABCD&quote;, &quote;Age&quote;:1}]">
   </object>
</root>
```

I am not sure if i have completely explained scenario, pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root><object attr="[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGH&quot;,&quot;Age&quot;:1}]"></object></root>'
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/root/object/@attr)[1] with string("[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ABCD&quot;, &quot;Age&quot;:1}]")')
select @XML
```

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes the best was not to hassle with string escaping at all. This will all be done implitly (besides the fact, that it is a difference if you use `&quot;` or `&quote;`):

```
DECLARE @XML XML = N'<root><object attr="[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ABCDEFGH&quot;,&quot;Age&quot;:1}]"></object></root>'

--We can use a *normal* string
DECLARE @newContent NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'[{"Name":"ABCD", "Age":1}]';

--We can place this string using `sql:variable()`
SET @XML.modify('replace value of (/root/object/@attr)[1] with sql:variable("@newContent")')

SELECT @XML;
```

The result

```
<root>
  <object attr="[{&quot;Name&quot;:&quot;ABCD&quot;, &quot;Age&quot;:1}]" />
</root>
```

As you can see, the escaping is done for you implicitly...

Hint: Trying to solve this yourself might stumble over some special characters you did not think about. This may pass all your tests and break in production... Worst case...